# How to add dynamic requires as external?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have 40+ json translation files that I want to dynamically require like this:

```
require(`./assets/locales/${lang}.json`)
```

Since webpack cannot determine the path at compile time, it will load every file in the directory (as explained [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/context-replacement-plugin/)). I don't want webpack to bundle these files in the `.js` output, so I added an `externals` configuration like this:

```
externals: [ 
    /assets\/locales\/.*\.json/i, 
    /assets\/locales\//i
],
```

The problem is that webpack will not consider the `externals` configuration with dynamic requires. It *does* work for non-dynamic requires such as:

```
require(`./assets/locales/en-us.json`)
require(`./assets/locales/pt-pt.json`)
```

But I don't want to add 40+ lines like this on my code... I want to have all these `.json` files as external dependencies, and be able to require them dynamically.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I looked into the [ContextReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/context-replacement-plugin/), but it doesn't seem to help me in this case. If I use the [IgnorePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/), I can't load the json files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! When webpack finds a require with expression, it proceeds to [import all files in the directory](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression). In these situations, webpack doesn't match the `externals` with a string or regex. It does work, however, if we use a function in our `externals` definition.

Here is how it turned out:

```
externals: [
    function (context, request, callback) {
        if (/assets\/locales$/i.test(context)) {
            return callback(null, './assets/locales/' + request);
        }
        callback();
    }
]
```

I there may be a better solution, maybe this is a webpack bug... If anyone has a better idea, I am open for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) like that:

```
require.context('./assets/locales/', false, /\.json$/);
```

> You can create your own context with the require.context() function.
>
> It allows you to pass in a directory to search, a flag indicating
>   whether subdirectories should be searched too, and a regular
>   expression to match files against.
>
> webpack parses for require.context() in the code while building.

If you prefer node there is a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-context) for that.
Let me know if it works. :)

Comment: maybe [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rossta/5a9edcd7ba37416f8c6f7ed383200b0d) can be helpful to understand

Comment: It didn't work per se but turned me to the solution: context. So, thanks!